# I don't get the my correct current time when i use time function in php

Tags: php

I try to get my current date and time of my location , but it does not give me my actual time , it only gives me the actual date

My Code:

```
<p><b>Current Date and Time</b></p>
<?php 
echo "<p>" . $curr_date_time = date("d F, Y (l) : h:i a") . "</p>";
?>
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: What actual specific output do you get? And what exactly did you expect? If you're seeing a different time than you expected, maybe your server is in a different timezone or something

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You use the server datetime, you need to change the `date_default_timezone_set` [More Details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Yeah, Thank you all for you help , my server is using Europe/Berlin timezone , i have modified it to my time zone and am getting my actual time. I really appreciate.

Comment: @Liam If you use your local time in all your server then its better to change it from `server administration` or `ssh`, or you will need to change it in each `PHP` file

Answer (score 1):

You need to change default timezone:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
echo "<p>" . $curr_date_time = date("d F, Y (l) : h:i a") . "</p>";

?>
```

More details : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

List of Supported Timezones : https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones

> Note: This list is based upon the timezone database version 2020.4.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Am getting my actual time!